# При нажатии на клавиши стрелок в терминале печатются крокозябры

Tags: linux, консоль

Я давно сталкиваюсь с этой проблемой, но всё никак не решался спросить и в гугле ничего не нашёл. Возможно это даже не баг, а фича линукса, но какая-то очень странная и неприятная фича.

Когда я запускаю в терминале интерпретатор lua и нажимаю на стрелки, то вместо передвижения курсора он печатает "`^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D`". Когда я хочу стереть слово целиком и нажимаю Alt+Backspace, то ничего не происходит, а по Ctrl+Backspace печатается "`^H`". Если же я хочу переместиться на слово влево и нажимаю Alt+Влево, он печатает "`^[[1;3D`".

Я не понимаю в чём причина. Изначально я думал, что в lua, но потом обнаружил, что nodejs ведёт себя абсолютно также. В качестве эмулятора терминала я использую xfce4-terminal, но причина и не в нём тоже, потому что вне иксов поведение терминала не меняется.

UPD: Чувствую что сейчас поймаю минусов, не знаю как меня так переклинило, но к nodejs это проблема всё же не относится, я ошибся. Когда-то давно что-то такое было в node, но это было давно (и возможно не правда). Я нашёл причину - у меня вместо lua прилинкован luajit и именно в нём такие баги, а в обычной lua всё в порядке.

Голосую за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: в bash'е всё нормально? какие-то костыли запуска интерпретаторов? необычное значение `$TERM`? необычный `inputrc`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer вроде как всё стандартно. А у вас такого нет? По-моему эта проблема преследовала меня всегда, на всех дистрибутивах.

Comment: не генте нет... ни в `node` ни в `lua` (5.1 или 5.4)... хотя в `luajit` воспроизводится... но в нём в принципе нет поддержки `readline`'а, так что оно и ожидаемо... на дебиане в `lua5.1` — тоже всё в порядке

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, вы правы. Я ошибся на счёт node. Извините и спасибо.

Comment: имхо, вместо закрытия вопроса лучше бы его отредактировать, а в ответе привести инфу о особенностях работы luajit. Для будущих покалений так сказать